# AngularJS: Show a list only when there is value in input field

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want a list of suggested tags to show beneath an input field *only* when a user has started typing into the input field. Currently I have this

jade

```
   div.form-group
      input#tags.form-control(name="tags", ng-model="query")
    div.form-group
      ul.suggested-tags
        li(ng-repeat="tag in tags | filter:query") {{tag.name}}
```

and this JS

```
  controller('TagsCtrl', function ($scope) {   
    $scope.tags = [
      {
        "name": "Foo",
        "id": "foo"
      },
      {
        "name": "Bar",
        "id": "bar"  
      }
    ]    
  })
```

What is the right way to set tags to `[]` if `query` is `null`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand you right you want to show tags only if someone started to type in text field.

Use `ng-show`.

On type you set `typeInProcess` to be `true`

```
div.form-group
  input#tags.form-control(name="tags", ng-model="query")
div.form-group
  ul.suggested-tags (ng-show="typeInProcess" )
    li(ng-repeat="tag in tags | filter:query") {{tag.name}}
```

For your text field add: ng-change="typeInProcess()"`.

After in controller, set:

```
 $scope.typeInProcess = false;

$scope.typeInProcess= function() {      
  $scope.typeInProcess = true;
};
```

Comment: for the input field: by ng-model = "item" do you mean ng-model="query" which is already present? and should that be typeInProcess(query) or just typeInProcess()?

Comment: i think its better to use different names for the different things (variable and function)...this general approach got me unstuck though..thanks!